# Does Jelly Bean have a shell?

Tags: android, unix, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to set up a little dev environment on my nexus 7 running jelly bean 4.2

The only shell I could find is a terminal emulator in the google play store which has no tools, no curl, not even the sudo commmand.

What does actually come with jelly bean and what do I need to do to get a shell on there with sudo access and tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root and install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) will give you some new commands. Use su instead of sudo to become super user (requires rooted phone).

You can also access the shell over adb by hooking your phone to a computer and running:

```
adb shell
```

Requires that you have ADB installed (it is a part of the [Android SDK from Google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html))